# @ZEND: How to make form label and element horizontally without decorators

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How to create form elements and labels horizontally without decorators help.

```
// Add the comment element
        $this->addElement('text', 'txt_password', array(
            'label'      => 'Password:',
            'required'   => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array(0, 20))
                )

        ));
```

Comment: Just give the class to an element & style accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tray its

$this->addElement('text', 'txt_password', array(

```
        'label'      => 'Password:',
        'required'   => true,
        'decorators' => array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Description',
            'Errors',
            array(array('elementDiv' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'span')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'span')),
         ),
        'validators' => array(
            array('validator' => 'StringLength', 'options' => array(0, 20))
            )

    ));
```